# What exactly is Schrodinger's Cat?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, superposition, schroedingers-cat

What exactly is [Schrodinger's Cat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger's_cat)? The little bit reading I did led me to believe that he wanted to assert the cat is dead OR alive only if you observe.
What does it signify? How did it affect the way we look at things?

Comment: Where did you read? Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schrödinger%27s_cat

Comment: I see what he wanted to assert. But why do we need the cat to be dead and alive? As long as we have not observed it, it could be dead OR alive and not dead AND alive.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows [insufficient prior research](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5778/what-counts-as-sufficient-prior-research-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: The cat is a very poor example of superposition because $|live\rangle$ and $|dead\rangle$ are not state vectors. At best they would be operators $\hat{live}$ and $\hat{dead}$, though whether even that is physically reasonable is debatable. If you want to understand superposition then read about [superposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_superposition) and put all thoughts of cats from your mind.

Comment: @SmitChaudhary - The whole point of the thought experiment is that the cat when not observed is in a state of being both dead AND alive. This may sound absurd to you, but that is precisely the point - to show to you how insane the laws of quantum mechanics are by putting it into the context of everyday objects such as cats.

Comment: @SmitChaudhary - In any case, it is not known to be a fact that the laws of quantum mechanics are indeed correct. All technology used today is based on them and would not work if not for these absurd properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Schrödinger's cat, is a thought experiment originally designed to show how ridiculous the Copenhagen interpretation of quantum mechanics was. It was not intended to support the dead and alive superpositions.

Comment: I answered the question, why the down vote?

Comment: Could the down voters please elaborate? Thanks